# Linux on Microblaze bigendian stop loading kernel virtual memory nexys2

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, microblaze

I'm trying to embed a light version of linux on microblaze bigendian on nexys2 board.
Memory: micronRam 16MB.

I compile the image with buildroot 2014.05
I'm loading the image with XMD after loading on the board the standard prog. test memory

Running the image with `con 0x85000000` stop at Kernel virtual memory, below what I get:

```
Early console on uartlite at 0x84000000
bootconsole [earlyser0] enabled
Ramdisk addr 0x00000000,
Compiled-in FDT at c027cc88
Linux version 3.14.4 (gmv@gmv-Inspiron-N5050) (gcc version 4.9.0 (Buildroot 2014         .05) ) #2 Tue Aug 26 22:20:19 WEST 2014
setup_cpuinfo: initialising
setup_cpuinfo: No PVR support. Using static CPU info from FDT
wt_msr_noirq
setup_memory: max_mapnr: 0x1000
setup_memory: min_low_pfn: 0x85000
setup_memory: max_low_pfn: 0x86000
setup_memory: max_pfn: 0x86000
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x85000000-0x85ffffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x85000000-0x85ffffff]
On node 0 totalpages: 4096
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0349df8, node_mem_map c0557000
  DMA zone: 32 pages used for memmap
  DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
  DMA zone: 4096 pages, LIFO batch:0
early_printk_console remapping from 0x84000000 to 0xffffd000
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping off.  Total pages: 4064
Kernel command line: console=ttyUL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 64 (order: -4, 256 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Memory: 10712K/16384K available (2547K kernel code, 106K rwdata, 676K rodata, 18
97K init, 186K bss, 5672K reserved)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xffffe000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xffffd000..0xffffe000  : early ioremap
  * 0xf0000000..0xffffd000  : vmalloc & ioremap
```

my dts file is

```
/*
 * Device Tree Generator version: 1.1
 *
 * (C) Copyright 2007-2013 Xilinx, Inc.
 * (C) Copyright 2007-2013 Michal Simek
 * (C) Copyright 2007-2012 PetaLogix Qld Pty Ltd
 *
 * Michal SIMEK <monstr@monstr.eu>
 *
 * CAUTION: This file is automatically generated by libgen.
 * Version: Xilinx EDK 14.7 EDK_P.20131013
 * Today is: Tuesday, the 26 of August, 2014; 18:57:24
 *
 * XPS project directory: device-tree_bsp_0
 */

/dts-v1/;
/ {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "xlnx,microblaze";
    model = "Xilinx MicroBlaze";
    aliases {
        serial0 = &xps_uartlite_0;
    } ;
    chosen {
        bootargs = "console=ttyUL0";
        linux,stdout-path = "/plb@0/serial@84000000";
    } ;
    cpus {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #cpus = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        microblaze_0: cpu@0 {
            bus-handle = <&mb_plb>;
            clock-frequency = <50000000>;
            compatible = "xlnx,microblaze-8.50.c";
            d-cache-baseaddr = <0x85000000>;
            d-cache-highaddr = <0x85ffffff>;
            d-cache-line-size = <0x10>;
            d-cache-size = <0x2000>;
            device_type = "cpu";
            i-cache-baseaddr = <0x85000000>;
            i-cache-highaddr = <0x85ffffff>;
            i-cache-line-size = <0x10>;
            i-cache-size = <0x2000>;
            interrupt-handle = <&xps_intc_0>;
            model = "microblaze,8.50.c";
            reg = <0>;
            timebase-frequency = <50000000>;
            xlnx,addr-tag-bits = <0xb>;
            xlnx,allow-dcache-wr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,allow-icache-wr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,area-optimized = <0x0>;
            xlnx,avoid-primitives = <0x0>;
            xlnx,base-vectors = <0x0>;
            xlnx,branch-target-cache-size = <0x0>;
            xlnx,cache-byte-size = <0x2000>;
            xlnx,d-axi = <0x0>;
            xlnx,d-lmb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,d-plb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,data-size = <0x20>;
            xlnx,dcache-addr-tag = <0xb>;
            xlnx,dcache-always-used = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dcache-byte-size = <0x2000>;
            xlnx,dcache-data-width = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-force-tag-lutram = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-interface = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-line-len = <0x4>;
            xlnx,dcache-use-fsl = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dcache-use-writeback = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-victims = <0x0>;
            xlnx,debug-enabled = <0x1>;
            xlnx,div-zero-exception = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dynamic-bus-sizing = <0x1>;
            xlnx,ecc-use-ce-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,edge-is-positive = <0x1>;
            xlnx,endianness = <0x0>;
            xlnx,fault-tolerant = <0x0>;
            xlnx,fpu-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,freq = <0x2faf080>;
            xlnx,fsl-data-size = <0x20>;
            xlnx,fsl-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,fsl-links = <0x0>;
            xlnx,i-axi = <0x0>;
            xlnx,i-lmb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,i-plb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-always-used = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-data-width = <0x0>;
            xlnx,icache-force-tag-lutram = <0x0>;
            xlnx,icache-interface = <0x0>;
            xlnx,icache-line-len = <0x4>;
            xlnx,icache-streams = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-use-fsl = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-victims = <0x8>;
            xlnx,ill-opcode-exception = <0x1>;
            xlnx,instance = "microblaze_0";
            xlnx,interconnect = <0x1>;
            xlnx,interrupt-is-edge = <0x0>;
            xlnx,lockstep-slave = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mmu-dtlb-size = <0x4>;
            xlnx,mmu-itlb-size = <0x2>;
            xlnx,mmu-privileged-instr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mmu-tlb-access = <0x3>;
            xlnx,mmu-zones = <0x2>;
            xlnx,number-of-pc-brk = <0x1>;
            xlnx,number-of-rd-addr-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,number-of-wr-addr-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,opcode-0x0-illegal = <0x1>;
            xlnx,optimization = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pc-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,pvr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pvr-user1 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pvr-user2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,reset-msr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,sco = <0x0>;
            xlnx,stream-interconnect = <0x0>;
            xlnx,unaligned-exceptions = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-barrel = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-branch-target-cache = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-dcache = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-div = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-ext-brk = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-ext-nm-brk = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-extended-fsl-instr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-fpu = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-hw-mul = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-icache = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-interrupt = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-mmu = <0x3>;
            xlnx,use-msr-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-pcmp-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-reorder-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-stack-protection = <0x0>;
        } ;
    } ;
    micron_ram: memory@85000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x85000000 0x1000000>;
    } ;
    mb_plb: plb@0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "xlnx,plb-v46-1.05.a", "xlnx,plb-v46-1.00.a", "simple-bus";
        ranges ;
        mdm_0: serial@84400000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,mdm-2.10.a", "xlnx,xps-uartlite-1.00.a";
            reg = <0x84400000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,interconnect = <0x1>;
            xlnx,jtag-chain = <0x2>;
            xlnx,mb-dbg-ports = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-bscan = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-uart = <0x1>;
        } ;
            flash@85000000 {
            bank-width = <2>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-mch-emc-3.01.a", "cfi-flash";
            reg = <0x85000000 0x1000000>;
            xlnx,include-datawidth-matching-0 = <0x1>;
            xlnx,include-datawidth-matching-1 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,include-datawidth-matching-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,include-datawidth-matching-3 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,include-negedge-ioregs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,include-plb-ipif = <0x1>;
            xlnx,include-wrbuf = <0x1>;
            xlnx,max-mem-width = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch-native-dwidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,mch-splb-awidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,mch-splb-clk-period-ps = <0x4e20>;
            xlnx,mch0-accessbuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch0-protocol = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mch0-rddatabuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch1-accessbuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch1-protocol = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mch1-rddatabuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch2-accessbuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch2-protocol = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mch2-rddatabuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch3-accessbuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mch3-protocol = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mch3-rddatabuf-depth = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mem0-width = <0x10>;
            xlnx,mem1-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,mem2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,mem3-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,num-banks-mem = <0x1>;
            xlnx,num-channels = <0x2>;
            xlnx,pagemode-flash-0 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pagemode-flash-1 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pagemode-flash-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pagemode-flash-3 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,priority-mode = <0x0>;
            xlnx,synch-mem-0 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,synch-mem-1 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,synch-mem-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,synch-mem-3 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,synch-pipedelay-0 = <0x2>;
            xlnx,synch-pipedelay-1 = <0x2>;
            xlnx,synch-pipedelay-2 = <0x2>;
            xlnx,synch-pipedelay-3 = <0x2>;
            xlnx,tavdv-ps-mem-0 = <0x14c08>;
            xlnx,tavdv-ps-mem-1 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,tavdv-ps-mem-2 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,tavdv-ps-mem-3 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,tcedv-ps-mem-0 = <0x14c08>;
            xlnx,tcedv-ps-mem-1 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,tcedv-ps-mem-2 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,tcedv-ps-mem-3 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,thzce-ps-mem-0 = <0x1f40>;
            xlnx,thzce-ps-mem-1 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,thzce-ps-mem-2 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,thzce-ps-mem-3 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,thzoe-ps-mem-0 = <0x1f40>;
            xlnx,thzoe-ps-mem-1 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,thzoe-ps-mem-2 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,thzoe-ps-mem-3 = <0x1b58>;
            xlnx,tlzwe-ps-mem-0 = <0x1388>;
            xlnx,tlzwe-ps-mem-1 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tlzwe-ps-mem-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tlzwe-ps-mem-3 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tpacc-ps-flash-0 = <0x61a8>;
            xlnx,tpacc-ps-flash-1 = <0x61a8>;
            xlnx,tpacc-ps-flash-2 = <0x61a8>;
            xlnx,tpacc-ps-flash-3 = <0x61a8>;
            xlnx,twc-ps-mem-0 = <0x14c08>;
            xlnx,twc-ps-mem-1 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,twc-ps-mem-2 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,twc-ps-mem-3 = <0x3a98>;
            xlnx,twp-ps-mem-0 = <0xd6d8>;
            xlnx,twp-ps-mem-1 = <0x2ee0>;
            xlnx,twp-ps-mem-2 = <0x2ee0>;
            xlnx,twp-ps-mem-3 = <0x2ee0>;
            xlnx,xcl0-linesize = <0x4>;
            xlnx,xcl0-writexfer = <0x1>;
            xlnx,xcl1-linesize = <0x4>;
            xlnx,xcl1-writexfer = <0x1>;
            xlnx,xcl2-linesize = <0x4>;
            xlnx,xcl2-writexfer = <0x1>;
            xlnx,xcl3-linesize = <0x4>;
            xlnx,xcl3-writexfer = <0x1>;
        } ;
        xps_intc_0: interrupt-controller@81800000 {
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-intc-2.01.a", "xlnx,xps-intc-1.00.a";
            interrupt-controller ;
            reg = <0x81800000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,kind-of-intr = <0x3>;
            xlnx,num-intr-inputs = <0x2>;
        } ;
        xps_timer_0: timer@83c00000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-timer-1.02.a", "xlnx,xps-timer-1.00.a";
            interrupt-parent = <&xps_intc_0>;
            interrupts = <1 0>;
            reg = <0x83c00000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,count-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,gen0-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,gen1-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,one-timer-only = <0x0>;
            xlnx,trig0-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,trig1-assert = <0x1>;
        } ;
        xps_uartlite_0: serial@84000000 {
            clock-frequency = <50000000>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-uartlite-1.02.a", "xlnx,xps-uartlite-1.00.a";
            current-speed = <115200>;
            device_type = "serial";
            interrupt-parent = <&xps_intc_0>;
            interrupts = <0 0>;
            port-number = <0>;
            reg = <0x84000000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,baudrate = <0x1c200>;
            xlnx,data-bits = <0x8>;
            xlnx,odd-parity = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-parity = <0x0>;
        } ;
    } ;
} ;
```

and config file

```
CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="rootfs.cpio"
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE is not set
CONFIG_EXPERT=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_EXTRA_PASS=y
# CONFIG_HOTPLUG is not set
# CONFIG_BASE_FULL is not set
# CONFIG_FUTEX is not set
# CONFIG_EPOLL is not set
# CONFIG_SIGNALFD is not set
# CONFIG_SHMEM is not set
CONFIG_SLAB=y
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG is not set
# CONFIG_OPT_LIB_ASM is not set
CONFIG_KERNEL_BASE_ADDR=0x85000000
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_FAMILY="spartan6"
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_MSR_INSTR=1
# CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_PCMP_INSTR is not set
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_BARREL=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_HW_MUL=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_DIV=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_FPU=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_MSR_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_PCMP_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_MMU=3
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_ICACHE=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_INTERRUPT=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_DCACHE=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_BRANCH_TARGET-CACHE=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_REORDER_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_STACK_PROTECTION=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXT_BRK=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXT_NM_BRK=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXTENDED_FSL_INSTR=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_HW_VER="8.50.a"
CONFIG_HZ_100=y
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y
CONFIG_NET=y
CONFIG_PACKET=y
CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_INET=y
# CONFIG_INET_LRO is not set
# CONFIG_IPV6 is not set
CONFIG_PROC_DEVICETREE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=8192
# CONFIG_NETDEVICES=y
# CONFIG_NET_ETHERNET=y
# CONFIG_XILINX_EMACLITE=y
# CONFIG_INPUT is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO is not set
# CONFIG_VT is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_HW_RANDOM is not set
# CONFIG_HWMON is not set
# CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y
# CONFIG_DNOTIFY is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_CIFS=y
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS=y
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS2=y
CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK=y
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG is not set
```

any help..
Thank for reading

Answer (score 0):

In your device-tree flash memory overlaps with RAM (micron_ram section) - do you execute the linux kernel directly from flash? Check that the kernel supports XIP (Execute in place).

Also check linux kernel in-memory log buffer (__log_buf) - maybe you found additional output:
http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Debugging+PowerPC+Kernel+Boot+Problems